# Do mplayer's audio filters contain the opposite of "Karaoke" Mode?

Tags: mplayer

A friend showed me mplayer's Karaoke mode (`-af karaoke`), and I was blown away by how good it is on the majority of the tracks I threw at it.

Instead of tweaking the 10-band EQ, is there an audio filter for the opposite of Karaoke Mode? Specifically, is there an audio filter that would allow me to "extract the vocals" and filter out the music?

Comment: `-af help` doesn't seem to list anything like this, third party modules for mplayer, if there is a such a thing, would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use a LADSPA plugin called [ladspacc](http://ptaff.ca/ladspacc/?lang=en_CA).  Note that the regular karaoke effect is a simple operation ([phase cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_Of_Phase_Stereo_%28OOPS%29)) while the opposite effect involves a complex signal processing chain; the ladspacc implementation will create slight sound artifacts.